# Slowness in SQL query with subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, query-optimization, sap-iq

My SQL query becomes too slow when a subquery is added in **WHERE** clause even though the individual run times of the queries is less than 1 minute.
The query has the following skeleton

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, sum(COL7) FROM TABLE1 
WHERE Col1 = 'something' AND COl2 = date AND Col3 = (SELECT MAX(COLUMN1) FROM TABLE2)
GROUP BY COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6
```

This query is running on SYBASE IQ.

Data for table 1 is 60M+ rows and post application of filter conditions is just 60 rows that usually takes 50 sec to run if subquery is replaced with hardcoded value.

Data for table 2 is 200 rows and post application of filter condition is just one integer value that individually takes 1 sec to run.

Comment: The code is syntactically incorrect.  The `WHERE` clause has no commas.  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the query should be doing would also help,.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Changed the "," to AND.
Also data for table 1 post application of filter conditions is just 60 rows that usually takes 50 sec to run if subquery is replaced with hard coded value.
Data for table 2 post application of filter condition is just one int value that individually takes 1 sec to run.

Comment: @GordonLinoff kindly have a look at the above comment and let me know if it helps.

Comment: if you're really looking to join all rows to a **single** `max()` value perhaps pull that **single** value into a variable and then feed the variable to the query (eg, `and col3 = @max_column1` (though IQ should be able to emulate this) ... or are you really looking to find the `max()` based on a correlated subquery/join?  at some point it would help to see the query plan as well as a complete list of the indexes for both tables; even 50 secs for a query in a `Sybase IQ` database sounds a bit excessive ... or is your real query more complicated than the one you've presented here?

Comment: @markp-fuso variable approach worked for me. Thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Move the subquery to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT t1.COL1, t1.COL2, t1.COL3, t1.COL4, t1.COL5, t1.COL6, sum(t1.COL7)
FROM TABLE1 t1 JOIN
     (SELECT MAX(COLUMN1) as max_column1 FROM TABLE2) t2
     ON t2.max_column1 = t1.date
WHERE Col1 = 'something' AND COl2 = date
GROUP BY COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6 ;
```

Then you want indexes on:

- `table1(col1, col2, date)`
- `table2(column1)`.

Comment: I will try the query out. Defining indexes is something not allowed to me.

Comment: Tried this out. No effect on the query execution time. It keeps on running.

Comment: @Sourabh . . . I think the correct indexes might be important.

Comment: I am only allowed to select the values to suffice my purpose. Creation of indexes or manipulation of any sort is not allowed by the DBA.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the subquery to the select and then use a join clause and see if that helps.

```
SELECT max(COLUMN1), COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, sum(COL7) 
FROM TABLE1 t1 join TABLE2 t2 
on t1.Col3 = t2.COLUMN1
WHERE Col1 = 'something' AND COl2 = date 
GROUP BY COLUMN1, COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6
```

Not that you are using parameters but it sounds weirdly like parameter sniffing.